# ipa become 30M+ larger archived by Xcode10?

Tags: size, archive, ipa, xcode10

The same project archived by Xcode 9.3 is smaller 30M+.
Is there anything I can do to reduce the size of ipa archived by Xcode 10.

Comment: I unzip the ipa, it turns out that the Assets.car file and PlugIns/widget become larger 15M.